# Passing URL as a parameter in httprequest plugin in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pass a URL as parameter to the httpRequest plugin in a jenkins pipeline , but it couldnt replace the paramater with its value

```
    httpRequest authentication: 'credauth', httpMode: 'POST', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: '${params.URL}'

    instead of ${params.URL} i also tried env.URL, ${URL}, param.URL  nothing seem to work
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For the groovy variable substitution, enclose them under double-quotes

httpRequest authentication: 'credauth', httpMode: 'POST', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: **"${params.URL}"**

Comment: Now i get  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: WorkflowScript
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:26)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
 at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
 at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)

Comment: Is that a build parameter?

Comment: If yes try "${env.URL}", remember the double quotes

Comment: URL: null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: null

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your jenkins configuration and jenkins file?